# SQL Most performance WHERE-clause

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, parameters, where-clause

In a Stored Procedure, I have a Parameter @ID that only has to apply when it is NOT NULL. What is the most performant way to code it? All 3 of them works...

```
-> table.ID = ISNULL(@param, table.column)
-> (ISNULL(@param ,0) = 0 OR table.column = @param)
-> 1 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@param ,0) = 0 THEN 1
       WHEN table.column = @param THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what do those `->`  mean?

Answer (score 0):

I will go with `Dynamic sql` to optimise this query

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql ='select * from yourtable ' + CASE WHEN @param IS NOT NULL THEN 'where table.COLUMN = '+@param ELSE '' END

EXEC (@sql)
```

Considering those parameters are not sent from application and there wont be any sql injection

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not an option because I have 15 parameters like this and a select statement that has 450 lines...

Comment: @DriesDG - You can make the query dynamic even with 15 parameters